# NullPointerException when passing Object from another Fragment to Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have problems trying to pass a custom object from Fragment to another Fragment so I can retrieve the data and add it to my Recyclerview. 
Fragment A:

```
    DarkSkyWeather fore = DarkSkyWeather.fromJson(response, i, timestamp, i);
    Forecast_Day_Fragment fdf = new Forecast_Day_Fragment();
    fdf.addItemsRecyclerForecast(fore);
```

Fragment B:

```
public class Forecast_Day_Fragment extends Fragment{

private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mForecastLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView mForecastRecyclerView;
public ArrayList<Forecast_Daily_Item> mForecast_daily_items = new ArrayList<>();
public Adapter_Daily_Forecast mDayForecast;
private static final String TAG = "Forecast_Day_Fragment";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forecast_layout, container, false);

    mForecastRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.fore_recycle);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(mForecastRecyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    mForecastLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mDayForecast = new Adapter_Daily_Forecast(mForecast_daily_items);
    mForecastRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mForecastLayoutManager);
    mForecastRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    mForecastRecyclerView.setAdapter(mDayForecast);

    return view;
}

public void addItemsRecyclerForecast(DarkSkyWeather skyWeather) {
   mForecast_daily_items.add(new Forecast_Daily_Item(R.drawable.sunny, skyWeather.getDailyTime(), skyWeather.getDailyTempLow(), skyWeather.getDailyTempHigh(), skyWeather.getDailySummary()));
    mDayForecast.notifyDataSetChanged(); //NullpointerException
}
```

}

Exception:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.aa.bb.Adapter_Daily_Forecast.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.aa.bb.Forecast_Day_Fragment.addItemsRecyclerForecast(Forecast_Day_Fragment.java:51)
                                                                   at com.aa.bb.WeatherController$6.onSuccess(WeatherController.java:620)
                                                                   at com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1$1.run(JsonHttpResponseHandler.java:152)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

I relative new to android programming and I never worked with Fragments before.
Thanks for your help!

Edit:

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started");

    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager_main);
    setUpViewPager(mViewPager);

}

private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new WeatherController());
    adapter.addFragment(new Forecast_Day_Fragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new MapsActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: plz show your code to add Fragment B into an activity.

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: yeah does FragmentB mean WeatherController in your context?

Comment: Fragment A is WeatherController. Fragment B is Forecast_Day_Fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:**

```
Forecast_Day_Fragment fdf = new Forecast_Day_Fragment();
```

At this time, fdf is just an object in memory. So all callback methods of fragment such as ***onCreate***, ***onCreateView*** (in this method you init adapter), etc... are not called yet. That why the next line.

```
fdf.addItemsRecyclerForecast(fore);
```

This line try to access the adapter in Fragment B, but it not initialized yet.

**Solution:** Pass data (in your case is fore) from FragmentA to MainActivity, then MainActivity will forward the data to FragmentB.
You should read this [link](https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments) to see how to pass data between fragments in viewpager.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The function addItemsRecyclerForecast gets called before creating the view.

So when addItemsRecyclerForecast is called, onCreateView hasn't been called yet.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought, but I tested it with log messages and onCreateView gets called before I call addItemsRecyclerForecast...

Comment: Nope, when you create dfd instant, that is another instant of Fragment B. the crash happens on another one.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I call the method without creating a new instance?